# How to get client IP from request inside haproxy docker container?

Tags: node.js, networking, docker, haproxy

I am trying to get the client's IP address from the request objects in my nodejs server.

My technology structure is:
I run two docker containers. One for `haproxy` and other for `nodejs` which uses `expressjs` framework. All incoming traffic is first received by haproxy which I use for proxying and load balancing. Haproxy forwards the requests to the appropriate backends based on the `ACLs` in the configuration file.

I tried accessing `x-forwarded-for` request header inside my nodejs but it only returned the IP for the docker network gateway interface `172.17.0.1`.

Heading over to `haproxy` configuration and using `option forwardfor header X-Client-IP` in the `defaults` block also set the `x-client-ip` header to the docker network gateway interface ip. Also the debug logs also are logging the same ip.

So this is what the trouble is. Since `haproxy` is running inside a container it believes that the docker network gateway interface is the client.

How can I get the actual client's IP to `haproxy` inside the container so that it can forward it to nodejs?

This is my `haproxy` configuration file:

```
global
    debug
    maxconn 4096

defaults
    mode http
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms
    timeout http-keep-alive 50000ms
    option http-keep-alive
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor header X-Client-IP

frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    acl is_api hdr_end(host) -i api.3dphy-dev.com

    use_backend api if is_api

    default_backend default

backend default
    server s0 "${DOCKER_INTERFACE_IP}:3000"

backend api
    balance leastconn
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    server s1 "${DOCKER_INTERFACE_IP}:17884"
```

I run my haproxy container using:

```
docker run -d --name haproxy_1 -p 80:80 -e DOCKER_INTERFACE_IP=`ifconfig docker0 | grep -oP 'inet addr:\K\S+'` -v $(pwd)/config/haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:ro haproxy:1.6
```

**Note:** I am not using any firewall. Also, feel free to suggest any improvements in my configuration. Keep-alive is also proving to be an issue.

Comment: I spend days to make this work. I've seen the horrors.... see answer below. I got a working haproxy:1.6 version also, but this wouldn't be the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally managed to find a solution after scouring through the docker forum.

The solution is a two step process.

First I needed to update my `haproxy` configuration to this:

```
global
    debug
    maxconn 4096

defaults
    mode http
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms
    timeout http-keep-alive 50000ms
    option http-keep-alive
    option http-server-close

frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    option forwardfor
    acl is_site hdr_end(host) -i surenderthakran-dev.com

    use_backend site if is_site

    default_backend default

backend default
    server s0 "${DOCKER_INTERFACE_IP}:3000"

backend site
    balance leastconn
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    server s1 "${DOCKER_INTERFACE_IP}:17884"
```

Notice the addition of `option forwardfor` in `frontend http-in` block. This tells the frontend part of haproxy to add the client IP to the request header.

Second, the docker run command should be updated to:

```
docker run -d --name haproxy_1 -p 80:80 -e DOCKER_INTERFACE_IP=`ifconfig docker0 | grep -oP 'inet addr:\K\S+'` -v $(pwd)/config/haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:ro --net=host haproxy:1.6
```

Notice the addition of `--net=host` option in the docker run command. It tells docker to launch the new container and use the same network card as the host.

Now the original client IP is added to the request header and can be accessed in the `x-forwarded-for` request header in any application to which the request is forwarded.

Comment: thanks for solution. notice that you don't need -p 80:80 option if you use host network. According to https://docs.docker.com/network/host/ when using host mode networking, ... and the -p, ... are ignored, producing a warning instead:
Also, if you use docker service --net=host should be replaced with --network host

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible the way haproxy works, since it keeps on throwing, when you don't connect the host at startup because it needs to resolve the address fully. I have tried a lot of workarounds (maybe it's possible), but I gave up and made this run with `docker-compose`

I posted a running example that might help earlier in a post.

The gist is to link the containers with a host that actually already exists. This is done by the docker linking.

> docker-compose.yml

```
api1:
  build: .
  dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
  ports:
    - 3955
  links:
    - mongo
    - redis
  environment:
    - REDIS_HOST=redis
    - MONGO_HOST=mongo
    - IS_TEST=true
  command: "node app.js"

api2:
  build: .
  dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
  ports:
    - 3955
  links:
    - mongo
    - redis
  environment:
    - REDIS_HOST=redis
    - MONGO_HOST=mongo
    - IS_TEST=true
  command: "node app.js"

mongo:
  image: mongo
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
  command: "--smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null"

redis:
   image: redis
   ports:
     - "6379:6379"

haproxy:
  image: haproxy:1.5
  volumes:
     - ./cluster:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/
  links:
    - "api1"
    - "api2"
  ports:
    - 80:80
    - 70:70
  expose:
    - "80"
    - "70"
```

> haproxy.cfg

```
global
  log 127.0.0.1 local0
  log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice

defaults
  log global
  mode http
  option httplog
  option dontlognull
  timeout connect 5000
  timeout client 10000
  timeout server 10000

listen stats :70
  stats enable
  stats uri /

frontend balancer
  bind 0.0.0.0:80
  mode http
  default_backend aj_backends

backend aj_backends
  mode http
  balance roundrobin
  option forwardfor
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
  http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
  option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost
  default-server inter 3s fall 5
  server api1 api1:3955
  server api2 api2:3955
```